# can't read custom property from linked material using python

Tags: python, materials, properties

I try to access my materials custom property's value using python. I use the following line of code to do that:

```
print(bpy.data.materials["MATERIAL NAME"]["CUSTOM PROPERTY NAME"])
```

what blender returns is this error:

> 1.0
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/PATH/TO/MY/SCRIPT/script.py", line XY, in 
>   KeyError: 'bpy_struct[key]: key "INSTANCING" not found'
>   Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

as you can see, before blender throws the error it actually logs my property's value. (1.0)

Since I am looping over all my scene's materials I did this to check if the Custom Property is existing:

```
hasattr(material, "CUSTOM PROPERTY NAME")
```

For whatever reason this is returning `FALSE` for all materials.

***Does it have something to do with the fact that the materials I am aiming for are a linked from other .blend files maybe?***

For me it's a dead end street for now, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @batFINGER that worked for me. Write it as an answer so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless defined as a `bpy.props` property `hasattr` won't work. . Use `material.get("prop")` or check `if "prop" in material.keys()`

Comment: btw, is it possible to loop over all available keys ?

Comment: `for key in material.keys(): value = material[key]`